# How to delete a file with file extension added in .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control

When I run `git rm -f "*.exe"` to delete `.exe` file. It throws the error

```
git rm AreaOfObjects.exe 
fatal: pathspec 'AreaOfObjects.exe' did not match any files
```

I wanted to ignore files ***.exe** while I commit my files, also I wanted to delete them from the local directory.

I wanted to make sure I don't commit those files mistakenly thus I added **.exe** extension to **.gitignore** But after making [out that throw over bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejvet.png) a commit the required file or before command doesn't work.

Comment: That file is already *not in Git*. Files in your working tree are not in Git; they are just files in your working tree. The files that *are* in Git are in commits, or are about to be in the *next* commit because they are in what Git calls its *index* or *staging area*, and that file is not in the current commit and not in the index / staging-area.

Comment: Note that `git rm` means: *remove this file both from Git's index **and** my working tree*. You'll need a different (non-Git) command if you only want to remove the file from your working tree.

Comment: Yes I can use some another Bash commands to delete the type of file I wanted to delete, But I am curious to know how can I do with git commands.

Comment: You can't. The Git commands are designed to operate on Git's files. (Technically, you can do it by first forcing the file to exist in Git's index, then using `git rm` to remove both the index and working tree copy. But that's a bad idea. Don't do it.)